# Uploading large files with WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using `ngResource` with Angular to upload a file to a ASP.NET web service.

It all works fine until I try files over a certain size (about 50MB). Somewhere after a certain size, the FromBody parameter is not getting bound, and I'm getting a `null` DocumentDTO object reference.

Any ideas how to fix it?

In my web.config I have these settings:

```
maxAllowedContentLength="500000000"
```

and

```
maxRequestLength="200000"
```

In my controller, I have:

```
[HttpPost, Route("{id:Guid}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Insert([FromUri]Guid id, [FromBody]DocumentDTO documentDTO)
{
    //...
```

My `DocumentDTO` is:

```
public class DocumentDTO
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

}
```

In my Angular controller, I have this code:

```
vm.document.$save(
            data => {

                notifications.success("The document has been uploaded to the repository.", "Upload Succeeded");

            },
            err => {

                errorService.handleApiError(err, "document", "upload");

            })
            .finally(() => vm.loading = false);
```

The `vm.document.content` value gets set by doing calling `readAsArrayBuffer` on a `FileReader`.

Like I said: this all works fine under a certain file size. Is the issue that the FileReader has a limit and is not setting the file content correctly, or the WebApi has a limit on the model binding?

Comment: Try using Postman or another HTTP client to test the file upload to the server.

Answer (score -1):

Please update maxRequestLength as well. Below is example of 2GB file.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you read that I'm setting maxRequestLength="200000". My file sizes will be under 150MB, so that should be sufficient.

Comment: Ah, yes I missed reading that.. trying here to replicate. Another option is spiting and merging files [link]https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1034347/Upload-large-files-to-MVC-WebAPI-using-partitionin